# how to change Dropdown values when user change language from language bar in angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, typescript2.0, postgresql-9.4

I have A table in database with two columns
1.EnglishName
2.PersianName
I return this two columns by web api and use it in my angular project

in angular project I use ngx-translate with two language
1.English
2.Persian

Now I want to load data dynamically to dropdownlist when user select a language from language bar.
for example
when user use English the dropdown values should get my EnglishName column data from api
and when user select Persian Language the dropdown values should get my PersianName column data from api.

app.component.ts:

```
import { navItemsDari } from '../../_nav';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  
  selector: 'app-dashboard,',
  templateUrl: './default-layout.component.html',
 
})
export class DefaultLayoutComponent {
  //public sidebarMinimized = false;
  public navItems = navItems;
  langChanged:boolean;
    
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.switchLang('English')
  }

  constructor(public _router: Router,public translate: TranslateService) {
    
    translate.addLangs(['English', 'دری']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('English');
  }
  switchLang(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang).sunscribe((res)=>{
this.langChanged=true;
});
   
  }
  onLogout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this._router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
  // toggleMinimize(e) {
  //   this.sidebarMinimized = e;
  // }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<span class="form-inline" id="language">
    <select class="form-control" #selectedLang (change)="switchLang(selectedLang.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let language of translate.getLangs()" [value]="language"
        [selected]="language === translate.currentLang">
        {{ language }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </span>
```

child.component.ts:

```
export class SubCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
  public showHideName:boolean = false;
  currentLang:boolean;
 constructor(private service: AdminServiceService,
  private toastr: ToastrService,private translate:TranslateService) {  
 
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
if(this.langChanged){
 if(this.translate.currentLang==='persian'){
  this.showHideName=true;
 }
 else if(this.translate.currentLang==='English'){
    this.showHideName=false;
 } 
}
}
```

child component.html

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="showHideName">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select Main Category</label>
                <select   name="name"  #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.name" class="form-control"    style="font-weight:bold;" >         
                    <option *ngFor="let pd of list" value="{{pd.id}}" >{{pd.name}}</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
          </div>
<SubCategoryComponent [langChanged]="langChanged"></SubCategoryComponent>
```

I want to show and hide div by changing the language
if User select English from language bar the div should be hidden
and if User Select Persian from Language bar the div should be shown automatically

can you help me Friends
thanks

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: If you provide your code here, we will be able to help better, but you can use translate.get and translate.stream methods to get the values of your dropdown once the language is changed

Comment: I have Edited My Question and add complete Code, Please see my Questions again with complete details Friends

Comment: @Vinita  I have edited my questions and add complete details with code please see my questions again you will find all code I have tried

Comment: @pc_coder I have edited my questions and add complete details with code please see my questions again you will find all code I have tried

Comment: @abdulwahid I have answered in details with code, try that and let me know if you need any more help

Comment: @Vinita Dear Vinita I changed my code as you said, I also edited my question as your answer please see my question again to find my mistakes. Because I have an error like ths: can't bind the langChanged since it isn't a known properly of "SubCategoryComponet" ... if SubCategoryComponent is an angular component then verify that it is a part of this module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

translate.use is a observable so you need to subscribe it and then on its completion pass some flag to child component that language has changed and then perform your logic.

```
switchLang(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang).subscribe((res)=>{
        this.langChanged = true;
    });
  }
```

use langChanged as input to the child component

```
<SubCategoryComponent [langChanged]="langChanged"></SubCategoryComponent>
```

child.component.ts:

```
@Input() langChanged: boolean;

ngOnChanges(): void {
           if(langChanged){
              if(this.translate.currentLang === 'Persian'){
                 this.showHideName=true;
              }
           else if(this.translate.currentLang === 'English'){
               this.showHideName=false;
           }
        }
     }
```

app. component. ts

```
langChanged:boolean;
```

Comment: can you give me more details, where and how I declare langChanged, should I declare it app.component.ts file or child.componet.ts file bro

Comment: I have modified the answer and added where you have to declare that variable for more info on input refer https://medium.com/@Zeroesandones/how-to-pass-data-from-parent-to-child-component-in-angular-9-dc7a0a64256c

Comment: @abdul wahid let me know if it worked and please mark the answer as correct if it worked

Comment: Thanks so much I will try it for tomorrow, if it work I will mark it as correct answers and if I need more details I will inform you sir

Comment: Dear Vinita I changed my code as you said, I also edited my question as your answer please see my question again to find my mistakes. Because I have an error like ths: can't bind the langChanged since it isn't a known properly of "SubCategoryComponet" ... if SubCategoryComponent is an angular component then verify that it is a part of this module

Comment: @abdulwahid I have found 2 issues: 
1) <SubCategoryComponent [langChanged]="langChanged"></SubCategoryComponent> this should be in your parent component (DefaultLayoutComponent)
2) you have missed @Input() langChanged: boolean; in your child.component.ts thus the error.

Comment: @abdulwahid solve above suggested issues, If you still face any issue add your code to a stackblitz URL I'll suggest the changes there.

Comment: Thanks, Your Answer was very helpful, wish you happy bro

Answer (score 0):

app.component.html

```
<div>
  <h2>{{ 'HOME.TITLE' | translate }}</h2>
  <label>
    {{ 'HOME.SELECT' | translate }}
    <select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)">
      <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="changeLang(lang)">{{ lang }}</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

//call your api and update value to lang

changeLang(lang){

lang === this.translate.currentLang;

}

ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-translate-example-nqx7wv Comment down your queries, if any will try to help it out. Consider accepting the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: I have edited my question and add complete details with code please check again my question

Comment: i think you need to modify the condition in child component.ts as =>  if(this.translate.currentLang == 'دری'){
  this.showHideName=true;
 }
 else if(this.translate.currentLang =='English'){
    this.showHideName=false;
 }

Comment: I also tried (this.translate.currentLang ) but it does not work, it always return English and don't switch to Persian